# The bootstrap (mdb) collapse do not show in the first click

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, mdbootstrap

When I click for the first time the collapse doesn't show and throw this error, but when I try to click more it works

[The error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9G2c.png)

This is my code:

```html
<button
          class="btn"
          data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
          data-mdb-target="#test"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="test"
        >
          TEST
   </button>
        
   <div class="collapse" id='test'>
      <ul class=" list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small mt-1 mb-0 ">
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Try changing data attributes, for example: data-mdb-toggle instead of data-toggle.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code is fine, I used jsfiddle as IDE.
I think you have to check scripts and links to your page about MDB.
If you used them locally change them with online CDN and check it.

```html
<!-- MDB -->
<link
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.js"
></script>
<button
          class="btn"
          data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
          data-mdb-target="#test"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="test"
        >
          TEST
   </button>
        
   <div class="collapse" id='test'>
      <ul class=" list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small mt-1 mb-0 ">
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qouz7kc2/1/